Ros2 ArUco pose estimation
I'm trying to detect and visualize pose using ArUco Marker. But, facing some issues with it while executing the node, the cv2.imshow will visualize the Aruco marker with bounding boxes and axis of it (including the xyz and rpy data). After that, i opened rviz and added pose, camera, tf in it. But it does not show the axis or the bounding box in the rviz.
This is the code:
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2
import numpy as np

class ArUcoDetectorNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('aruco_detector_node')

        # Load previously saved camera calibration data
        self.declare_parameter('camera_calibration_path', '/Calibration_result/camera_calibration.npz')
        calibration_path = self.get_parameter('camera_calibration_path').get_parameter_value().string_value

        with np.load(calibration_path) as data:
            self.mtx = data['camera_matrix']
            self.dist = data['dist_coeff']

        # Initialize CvBridge
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        # Subscribe to the camera info and image topics
        self.image_sub = self.create_subscription(
            Image,
            '/camera/camera/color/image_raw',
            self.image_callback,
            10
        )

        self.camera_info_sub = self.create_subscription(
            CameraInfo,
            '/camera/camera/color/camera_info',
            self.camera_info_callback,
            10
        )

        # Publisher for pose data
        self.pose_pub = self.create_publisher(PoseStamped, 'aruco_pose', 10)

        # ArUco marker dictionary and detector initialization
        self.aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_250)
        self.aruco_params = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()

        self.marker_length = 0.08  # Marker length in meters (8 cm)

    def camera_info_callback(self, msg):
        # Save camera calibration parameters when received
        self.camera_matrix = np.array(msg.k).reshape(3, 3)
        self.dist_coeffs = np.array(msg.d)

    def image_callback(self, msg):
        # Convert ROS Image message to OpenCV format
        frame = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, desired_encoding='bgr8')

        # Convert the frame to grayscale for ArUco detection
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Detect ArUco markers in the input frame
        marker_corners, marker_ids, rejected_candidates = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(gray, self.aruco_dict, parameters=self.aruco_params)

        # Verify that at least one ArUco marker was detected
        if marker_ids is not None and len(marker_corners) > 0:
            for marker_corner, marker_id in zip(marker_corners, marker_ids.flatten()):
                # Extract the marker corners
                corners = marker_corner.reshape((4, 2))
                (top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left) = corners

                # Estimate pose of the marker
                rvec, tvec, _ = cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers([corners], self.marker_length, self.mtx, self.dist)

                # Draw the marker and axis on the frame
                cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, marker_corners, marker_ids)
                cv2.drawFrameAxes(frame, self.mtx, self.dist, rvec[0], tvec[0], 0.05)  # Axis length 0.05 meters

                # Create PoseStamped message
                pose_stamped_msg = PoseStamped()
                pose_stamped_msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
                pose_stamped_msg.header.frame_id = "camera_link"  # Frame reference

                # Set position
                pose_stamped_msg.pose.position.x = tvec[0][0][0]
                pose_stamped_msg.pose.position.y = tvec[0][0][1]
                pose_stamped_msg.pose.position.z = tvec[0][0][2]

                # Set orientation (as a quaternion)
                rotation_matrix, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec[0])
                quaternion = self.rotation_matrix_to_quaternion(rotation_matrix)
                pose_stamped_msg.pose.orientation.x = quaternion[0]
                pose_stamped_msg.pose.orientation.y = quaternion[1]
                pose_stamped_msg.pose.orientation.z = quaternion[2]
                pose_stamped_msg.pose.orientation.w = quaternion[3]

                # Publish pose data
                self.pose_pub.publish(pose_stamped_msg)

                # Optionally print the pose
                self.get_logger().info(f"Marker ID: {marker_id}, Pose: {tvec}")

        # Display the result frame with markers and axes
        cv2.imshow('ArUco Detection', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    def rotation_matrix_to_quaternion(self, rotation_matrix):
        # Convert a rotation matrix to quaternion
        tr = rotation_matrix[0][0] + rotation_matrix[1][1] + rotation_matrix[2][2]

        if tr > 0:
            S = np.sqrt(tr + 1.0) * 2
            qw = 0.25 * S
            qx = (rotation_matrix[2][1] - rotation_matrix[1][2]) / S
            qy = (rotation_matrix[0][2] - rotation_matrix[2][0]) / S
            qz = (rotation_matrix[1][0] - rotation_matrix[0][1]) / S
        else:
            i = 0
            if rotation_matrix[1][1] > rotation_matrix[0][0]:
                i = 1
            if rotation_matrix[2][2] > rotation_matrix[i][i]:
                i = 2

            j = (i + 1) % 3
            k = (i + 2) % 3

            S = np.sqrt(rotation_matrix[i][i] - rotation_matrix[j][j] - rotation_matrix[k][k] + 1.0) * 2
            qw = (rotation_matrix[k][j] - rotation_matrix[j][k]) / S
            qx = 0.25 * S
            qy = (rotation_matrix[j][i] + rotation_matrix[i][j]) / S
            qz = (rotation_matrix[k][i] + rotation_matrix[i][k]) / S

        return [qx, qy, qz, qw]

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    aruco_detector_node = ArUcoDetectorNode()

    rclpy.spin(aruco_detector_node)

    # Clean up
    aruco_detector_node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Ros2 Humble
opencv-contrib-python 4.10.0
Ubuntu 22.04
Camera Intel RealSense D435i
Thanks in advance.
